# how to skip Preflight Requset in vue with content-type:application/json

Tags: vue.js, post, request

error :"405 not allowed Method" in post method type call in request command vue

i need call api function with content-type:application/json and post Method type with request  command in vue ,but  browser add preflight request with options method type and it causes this error :"405 not allowed Method"

```
   var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://api.sample.com/login",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Request-Method":"POST",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: '{ Username: "demo", Password: "demo", Domain: "test" }'
  };

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    body.data;
    alert("ok");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `OPTIONS` call is done whenever you do a cross-origin request. This means the domain your application is running on is different from the domain where the api is. A pre-flight request is mandatory for these requests, because the browser needs to figure out if you are allowed to do these requests. A 405 error means that the server thinks you are not allowed to make that request.

To solve this problem you can move your api to the same domain as your frontend. Please note that it cannot be on a subdomain.

A different way of solving this, is by sending back the correct headers. In your case you seem to at least miss the [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) response header. Make sure to send this header and either dynamically figure out which methods are allowed, or do something like the following. That would allow the most common methods to work.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
```

---

In the comments you said that you do not have control over the api, and as such cannot change the response header. In that case your best bet is to contact whoever maintains the api and ask how to best use their api.

---

In the comments you said that this worked fine when you did the same thing in ASP.NET. ASP.NET is a server-side language, which means that requests in that context do not have a concept of "cross-origin". Cross-origin only comes into play in the browser, where the application runs on an actual domain.

Assuming you can set up a proxy on your application domain, you can also create a proxy that proxies all requests to the api you actually want to communicate with. You would deploy your domain on `https://example.com` and do your requests to `https://example.com/api/endpoint`. Your proxy will listen for requests that begin with `https://example.com/api` and proxy it to `https://whatever.the.api.is/` with the appropriate endpoint and data.

Please keep in mind that while some api's might just be configured incorrectly, a lack of cross-origin response headers might just mean that the api is nog meant to be consumed through the browser. Part of this could be that the request contains a secret that should not be exposed to users that use your application, but should instead only be on the server. Using a proxy in that case would set you up for impersonation attacks, because you would expose the secret to your application, but defeat the cross-origin headers by making it appear to the application that the api is on the same domain.

Comment: thanks; i am do not access the api for change header

Comment: If you do not have control over the api, contact the maintainer of the api to figure out how you are supposed to interact with it.

Comment: I successfully used this API in asp.net but when i call it in JS it causes 405 error